# How do I prevent a memory card from mounting in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, mount

Using Ubuntu Windows installer, I dual boot Ubuntu 11.10 with Windows 7. I have an SD card for Readyboost which is seen and mounted when Ubuntu loads.

How can I stop the Linux OS from mounting the SD card?

Comment: Would you be fine with disabling automounting for all drives? See also: [Disable auto-mount for particular partitions on USB drives](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25110/disable-auto-mount-for-particular-partitions-on-usb-drives)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is to go into fstab and write a line with the auto mount set to noauto mount. You have to be signed in as Sudo to do so.

Here is an article that describes the auto mount and fstab process.
I use fstab to auto mount drives on other pcs on our network so they should up as devices on my pc, this allows me to back them up as local.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/38125/htg-explains-what-is-the-linux-fstab-and-how-does-it-work/

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11357756&posted=1#post11357756), which states:

1. Go to Ubuntu Software Center
2. Under system search for Gnome Partition Editor and install it
3. System->Administration->GParted
4. Right click on the system reserved partition and click manage flags
5. Check hidden

I did this for the SD card and now it's not mounting.